# Deep liking does not work on gmail app and works on other browsers

Tags: android, deep-linking

https://example.com/public/change_phone?email_recovery_code=F08fjfU39Ea6RSlDzM8ZZJFVwyjAE

```
<activity android:name=".view.activity.sign_in_new_number.SignInNewNumberActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                    <data
                            android:scheme="https"
                            android:host="example.com"
                            android:pathPrefix="/public/change_phone"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
```

I used the manifest setting's like above but it does not work for Gmail app, the URL does not redirect me on my app just open's the link in Gmail app

Comment: Any solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

if splash screen is the first screen in your app..then use this on onCreate() of your splash activity :

First get the url you are getting through deep linking

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Uri data = intent.getData();

if (!isTaskRoot()) {//this will resume your app from last loaded screen if you pressed home button earlier
        Log.e("splashfin", "hello");
        if (data != null) {

  //open that activity through your url or do what ever you want
  }else{}

}else{
if(data!=null){
        //open that activity through your url or do what ever you want

}

 }
```

Comment: The question is different and the solution you provided is for params not for app redirection